# How to set cookie expiration date to a month?

Tags: javascript, function, cookies

i just need to set this function to expire in one month, can someone tell me how to do it?

```
function _saveUserPreference() {
    // Set the cookie expiry to one year after today.
    var expiryDate = new Date();
    expiryDate.setFullYear(expiryDate.getFullYear() + 1);
    document.cookie = cookieName + '=y; expires=' + expiryDate.toGMTString();
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need add one month to the `expiryDate` var:

```
  var expiryDate = new Date();
  expiryDate.setMonth(expiryDate.getMonth() + 1);
```

Comment: Hi there, what happens if current month is december(11) then january(1) won't be expiryDate < currentMonth it won't trigger.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't have enough points to comment, but to piggyback on @ianaya89's answer.

```
let expiryDate = new Date();
const month = (expiryDate.getMonth() + 1) % 12;
expiryDate.setMonth(month);
```

new Date = gets today's date.
Then, the next line is to get next month. We use modulo for the edge case where it is currently December and we want it to return 1, instead of 13.
We then set variable, expiryDate (now one month ahead), to our cookie.

Comment: It'd be better if you could include explanation for your code.

Comment: new Date = gets today's date. Then, the next line is to get next month. We use modulo for the edge case where it is currently December and we want it to return 1, instead of 13. We then set variable expiryDate, now one month ahead, to our cookie.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function _saveUserPreference(){
        var montharr = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31],
            expiryDate = new Date(),
            year = expiryDate.getFullYear(),
            month = expiryDate.getMonth(),
            date = expiryDate.getDate();

        var newMonth, newYear;

        expiryDate.setMonth(month+1);

        newMonth = expiryDate.getMonth();

        newYear = expiryDate.getFullYear();
        // when expiryDate is 2014-01-31, setMonth(m+1),then expiryDate is 2014-03-03 or 2014-03-02
        if(newMonth - month > 1 ){

            if( isLeapYear(year) && newMonth === 2 ){
                expiryDate.setDate(29);
                expiryDate.setMonth(1);
            }else{
                expiryDate.setDate(montharr[newMonth-1]);
                expiryDate.setMonth(newMonth-1);
            }
        }

        document.cookie = cookieName + '=y; expires=' + expiryDate.toGMTString();

        // if you mean a month to 30 days

        /*var now = new Date(),
            milliSeconds = now - 0 + 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
            expiryDate = new Date(milliSeconds);

        document.cookie = cookieName + '=y; expires=' + expiryDate.toGMTString();*/

    }

    function isLeapYear(year){

        if( year%4 === 0 && year%100 !== 0 ){
            return true;
        }

        if( year%100 === 0 && year%400 === 0 ){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Why that big code? He only wants add one month to the current date.

Comment: I don't think so thats really important to keep the exact number of days in a month just to save a cookie :/